# How to update text in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, label

I have here a long method that takes a little while to execute. I would like to keep the user entertained so I created a progress bar and a label. What I would like is for that label to change while the system executes the progress. Ive been looking at Application.DoEvents(), but it seems like thats the wrong way to go. This application is pretty simple and its just a project and nothing professional. All this app does is send a file to a client and insert the data into a database.

I have one label (besides a success and error label), that I would like to constantly update along side the progress bar. Any ideas or tips on how to do this? Would Application.DoEvents() be acceptable in this situation? Or is there a simple way to update the text. I am using C#, asp.net, and a System.Web.UI.Page. Any help or pointing me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PutFTPButton.Enabled = false;
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    KaplanFTP.BatchFiles bf = new KaplanFTP.BatchFiles();
    KaplanFTP.Transmit transmit = new KaplanFTP.Transmit();
    //label text change here
    if (btn.ID == PutFTPButton.ID)
    {
        //bf.ReadyFilesForTransmission();
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Kaplan");

        FileInfo[] BatchFiles = bf.GetBatchFiles(dir);

        bool result = transmit.UploadBatchFilesToFTP(BatchFiles);
        //label text change here
        if (!result)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text += KaplanFTP.errorMsg;
            return;
        }

        bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("CTL");
        bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("HDR");
        bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("DET");
        bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("NTS");
        List<FileInfo> allfiles = BatchFiles.ToList<FileInfo>();
        allfiles.AddRange(dir.GetFiles("*.txt"));
        bf.MoveFiles(allfiles);
        //label text change here
        foreach (string order in bf.OrdersSent)
        {
            OrdersSentDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(order + "<br />"));
        }
        //lblWait.Visible = false;
        OrdersSentDiv.Visible = true;
        OrdersInfoDiv.Visible = false;
        SuccessLabel.Visible = true;
        NoBatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = true;
        BatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = false;
        PutFTPButton.Enabled = false;
        BatchesCreatedLbl.Text = int.Parse(NextBatchNum).ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(20000);

        if (KaplanFTP.errorMsg.Length != 0)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            SuccessLabel.Visible = false;
            ErrorLabel.Text = KaplanFTP.errorMsg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use an Ajax UpdateProgress control, check [Progress Bar on File Upload ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1107392.aspx/1).

**EDIT:** Another one [Displaying Progress Bar For Long Running Processes using ASP.NET AJAX](http://devarchive.net/displaying_progress_bar_for_long_running_processes.aspx).

Comment: Interesting. I havent tried putting the labels actually INSIDE the progress control. Currently only the GIF is there. Would the program be able to read the labels even if their in a ajax control?

Comment: @javasocute Yes it can, but as much as I know you don't need any labels that is the point of UpdateProgress you can use an Image(asp:Image is what I use) that say Uploading or what you wish.Check the new link I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else this.label1.Text = text;
    } 
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        SetText(yourVariable.ToString());
    }
```

if i understand you correctly this should work.

Comment: Im pretty new to c#, would you mind explaining what this does and how this works?

Comment: well,, i thought you were working on winform. this wont work on asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Application.DoEvents() is not available in an ASP.NET application, nor is it's use acceptable in a standard WinForms application with the advent of multicore processors and the .NET threading library.

A web application requires communication to/from a server.  Therefore simply updating the text of a label does nothing unless you are sending that back to the client.  In your case you would need an event which was signaled by this line (because it is a batch upload):

```
transmit.UploadBatchFilesToFTP(BatchFiles);
```

The event would update the value you want to display.  You would then need some AJAX code (or an ASP.NET update panel around a ASP.NET label) on the web page in question to get and display the new value.

HTH